# How to find all installed applications

Tags: bash, macos

I'm trying to use `find` to list all installed applications. `find /Applications -name "*.app"`. But this returns a list like:

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/crashreporter.app
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/plugin-container.app
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/updater.app
```

Using `find /Applications -name "*.app" -exec basename {} \;` returns a list like:

```
DVD Player.app
FaceTime.app
Firefox.app
```

This is better but what I want listed is the application and the directory its stored in: `/Applications/Firefox.app`

How can I list all installed applications without also listing the subdirectories within the application itself?

Comment: `find /Applications -name \*.app | grep -v "\/Contents\/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask System Profiler

```
system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType
```

which gives you more information as just the path, optionally also xml formatted

```
system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType -xml
```

Answer (score 1):

you might try

```
find /Applications -maxdepth 1 -name "*.app" -type d
```

Here, `-type d` limits the search just to directories, while `-maxdepth 1` restricts the "recursion level"

Comment: I thought this might work but `find /Applications -maxdepth 1 -name "*.app" -type d | wc -l` shows only 60 applications installed whereas `find /Applications -name "*.app" -exec basename {} \; | wc -l` shows 200+ applications installed. Even `find /Applications -maxdepth 3 -name "*.app" -type d | wc -l`only shows 96 applications installed. And with `-maxdepth 4` it returns things like `Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/crashreporter.app`

Comment: if I understood your question correctly, the command `find /Applications -name "*.app" -exec basename {} \; | wc -l` does something slightly else - it descends to all levels and strips the directory part of the path - for example `find /Applications/Firefox.app -name "*.app" -exec basename {} \;` on my system returns `Firefox.app`, `crashreporter.app`, `plugin-container.app`, `updater.app` - I suppose you are interested just in "Firefox.app" and not the rest?

Comment: Ah that explains the much higher number of applications. I didn't realize it was still returning the same `Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/crashreporter.app` stripped of its directory. What I'd like is to be able to list the directory as well which you solution does accomplish. But if I had some application hidden 5 levels down this solution wouldn't be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
find /Applications -printf "%f\n"|grep "\.app"
```

with .app in final of name

```
find /Applications -printf "%f\n"|grep "\.app"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will find all applications, even in subdirectories:

```
find                  \
      /Applications   \
      -iname "*.app"  \
      -type d         \
| grep  -v  '\.app.*\.app'
```

`-type d` means look for directories, since applications are actually directories.

`grep -v` means filter out matching entries...

matching `\.app.*\.app` as a regular expression meaning "*.app is listed twice*"